# Is it possible to send a email through Batch file

Tags: email, batch-file

Is it possible to send an email through a batch command line? I have a password batch file for a folder and when you fail three attempts i want it to send me an email. I know its possible to download ans install a program off the internet but when I would open the program it would close. So is there a command or program that sends and email through batch?

Answer (score 0):

[TakeCommand](http://www.jpsoft.com) will enable all kinds of commandline-magic, including [sending of mail](http://jpsoft.com/help/index.htm?sendmail.htm). Alkternatively, if you have a local install of PHP (and properly set it up), you could write a PHP-Script to send mail and launch the PHP-Interpreter (in your batch) to execute that file.